# How to transfer ETH on Rinkeby using ethers.js

Tags: smartcontracts, erc20, ethers.js, etherscan

Is there anybody who can help me with transfer ETH programmatically using `ethers.js`?

I have some ETH on Rinkeby and want to transfer it to any address programmatically.

[image: Balance on Rinkeby]

Please let me know the address of ETH contract and how to transfer using `ethers.js`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I suggest reading about the [ethers.js](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/) library. This is a great library for working with evm networks.

Then let's consider two options:

1. sending **with** wallet like Metamask;
2. sending **without** wallet using private key.

Let's start with the wallet option. This example can be found on the ethers.js documentation site:

```js
// A Web3Provider wraps a standard Web3 provider, which is
// what MetaMask injects as window.ethereum into each page
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum)

// MetaMask requires requesting permission to connect users accounts
Await provider.send("eth_requestAccounts", []);

// The MetaMask plugin also allows signing transactions to
// send ether and pay to change state within the blockchain.
// For this, you need the account signer...
const signer = provider.getSigner()

// Sending 1 ETH
const tx = signer.sendTransaction({
    to: destAddress,
    value: ethers.utils.parseEther("1.0")
});
```

Now an option if we don't have a wallet like Metamask, but we have a private key:

```js
// The JsonRpcProvider is a popular method for interacting with Ethereum
const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider("ADDRESS OF RINKEBY RPC");

// Create a new Wallet instance for privateKey and connected to the provider.
const wallet = new Wallet("TOP SECRET PRIVATE KEY", provider);

// Sending 1 ETH
wallet.sendTransaction({
    to: destAddress,
    value: ethers.utils.parseEther("1.0")
})
```

Comment: Thanks Pobepto. It was great helpful.

Comment: Don't forget to accept answer if it was helpful :)

Comment: Got it. I will after checking. lol

Answer (score -2):

A quick Google search would've done the job, but check [this](https://piyopiyo.medium.com/how-to-send-ether-with-ethers-js-b1bb0b17a855) out

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks Niccolò Fant. I will check it out.